# Not able to use facebook JS SDK correctly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using facebook JS SDK for user login. I am confused on how it is working. When I am using this code:

```
FB.init({
        appId     : '*********************************',
        channelURL: '*********************************',
        cookie    : true, 
        xfbml     : true,
        oauth     : true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'connected') {

    }
        else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {
            /* Not Authorized */
            login();
        }
        else {
            /* Not Logged In*/
            /*login();*/
        }
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}; /* method window.fbAsyncInit ends here*/
/* Checks user login status on facebook*/
function login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //connected

        }
        else {
            //cancelled
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
} /*function login ends here*/
```

I am not able to get the user email id.

While if i am using this one it is giving me user email id.

```
FB.init({
        appId     : '********************',
        channelURL: '********************',
        cookie    : true, 
        xfbml     : true,
        oauth     : true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'connected') {
            /* Connected Successfully */
            FB.login(function(response) {
                // handle the response
                if (response.authResponse) {

        }
        else {
            //cancelled
        }
            }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});              
}
        else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {
            /* Not Authorized */
            login();
        }
        else {
            /* Not Logged In*/
            /*login();*/
        }
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
}; /* method window.fbAsyncInit ends here*/
/* Checks user login status on facebook*/
function login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //connected

        }
        else {
            //cancelled
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
} /*function login ends here*/
```

I am getting the email id.

Please point me where I am doing wrong in the first code ?

Edited: As per suggestion I have added the {scope: 'email,user_likes'} in the login function but still not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Case 1: I am not able to get the user email id.

The only reason could be that the user is **already authorized** before you made these changes. Try using the same code again with a new user or by removing the app from your [App settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications).

Comment: Hi Sahil,

Thanks for response. I did what you said but I am still not able to get the email id.

Comment: Try debugging the flow of the code using `console.log`. Check  what's the value of `response.status` in `getLoginStatus()` , also check whether the code is moving in `FB.Login()` or not.

Comment: Hi Sahil,
You were correct. Code was not moving to FB.Login(). Thanks for pushing me in right direction. Its working now.

Answer (score -1):

the trick is to add {scope: 'email,user_likes'}...
In first code you are missing this part which is there in the second code. It will allow you to get the e-mail id of the user as well as his likes also...

Comment: Hi ABCD, I have edited the question, but it is still not working.

Comment: change to else {
            /* Not Logged In*/
            login();
        }....that is uncomment login() function there..